# How do align intertext with math instead of an awkward space?

Tags: spacing, align, intertext

When you use the `\intertext` in the `\align*` environment with the amsmath package, it has a small vertical space between the displayed text and equation even though it is still coded on the same line as the equation.

In a regular line of code, you can type `\intertext{text}` (generic equation) on the one line. Yet, when it is compiled, it visual output shows a small vertical space between the text and the equation that I did not add manually.

I am using `\intertext` because it is left-aligned and I don't want the equation itself to be left-aligned, just the text, but it should also be on the same displayed line as the `\intertext`.

Comment: Please, please, please show us a short compilable code resulting in your issue. Please learn from older comments, I asked you to do so in your last question too ... Simply help us to help you!

Comment: @user14554: It's not clear what you mean by `\intertext` being on the same line as the math display. Are you talking about your code, or the output? If you just want some textual display, use `\text`, not `\intertext`.

Comment: @user14554: Stick to the script. You have a problem and we're here to solve it. Can you answer my question?

Comment: @user14554: Okay, so you use `\intertext` and it inserts a (vertical) gap. That's what it's meant to do. If that's not what you want, then what do you want? Do you just want to insert text? Then use `\text` as I suggested...

Comment: I want it to *not* insert a vertical gap because I see no alternative to forcing inter-equational text to be left-aligned. The `\text` command will automatically center with the rest of the columns in the output instead of keeping the text left aligned, and when I try using `\flalign` inside a `\text` command, I get an error.

Comment: @user14554: You want non-left-aligned `\intertext` it seems. `\text` doesn't centre its contents.

Comment: I do want left-aligned `\intertext`, I just don't want the vertical gap that it for some reason automatically has. If there was a command that did exactly what `\intertext` did but without the vertical gap, that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If `\intertext` inserts too much vertical space between the equation components, then consider using `\shortintertext` from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
           f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ax^2 + bx + c &= f(x)          \\
\intertext{here is some \texttt{intertext}}
           f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ax^2 + bx + c &= f(x)          \\
\shortintertext{here is some \texttt{short intertext}}
           f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ax^2 + bx + c &= f(x)          \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
\intertext{here is some \texttt{intertext}} \\[-2.2\normalbaselineskip]
           f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ax^2 + bx + c &= f(x)
\end{align*}  

\end{document}
```

If you really don't like the space around either, you can use the optional argument of `\\[<len>]` to insert negative vertical space and shrink the gap to suit your needs (the last option in the above code).

Comment: It seems shortintertext has the same problem of creating a vertical gap. I tried copying and pasting `\\[<len>]` inside the align* environment in different locations but all I got was the error "treated as zero" or "misplaced tab character".

Comment: @user14554: You need a length where I have `<len>`; something like ``\\[-20pt]``.

Comment: Okay then, `\\[<length>pt]` seems to do the trick, but is there anything that specifies exactly how big the `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` vertical gap is to completely get rid of it without adding too much space? All I want is to get rid of the gap that `\intertext` causes, going over that would likely cause errors down the document.

Comment: @user14554: `\intertext` inserts a gap of `\belowdisplayskip` *above* it and `\abovedisplayskip` *below* it. `\shortintertext` uses a default `3pt` above and below.

Comment: 3pt is much to small to close the gap, but -30 in the `\\[...]` seems aligned. Is -30pt what you meant? It's a good guess but the real  spacing could be 35pt or 29pt, the ams manual doesn't seem to specify.